# Select item under async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I have simple search component that is basic implementation of a real component.

Idea is that the `<ion-list>` contains more complex entries(objects) and I want select items from this list by click on `<ion-item>`.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-searchbar [formControl]="searchControl">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item 
        *ngFor="let entry of entries | async; let entryIndex = index;"
        (click)="selectItem(entryIndex)">
        {{ entry.title }} - {{ entry.description }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>`
})
export class SearchPage {
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  public entries: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(private search: Search) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.entries = this.searchControl
      .valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(query => this.search.byKeyword(query));
  }

  selectItem(entryIndex: number) {
     // ...
  }

}
```

Question is how can I select item from observable array entries by index?

If I try something like this:

```
selectItem(entryIndex: number) {
  this.entries
    .map((entries: any[]) => entries[entryIndex])
    .subscribe(data => console.info("Selected entry", data));
}
```

I'll get nothing(which is logically)

Comment: Is there a special reason to use the index instead using the object itself? :)

Comment: @mxii It could solve that case but the question is more general.  I can implement this component in anyway, but for my curiosity it's really important question.
I have this component implemented in the "angular 1" way with data binding and a synchronous code, but I guess its not "true" for the angular 2 when it comes with the new features for special cases like this one

Comment: So you have to subscribe that Observable and copy the results into a local variable.. Or take a look at the `BehaviorSubject`, which caches the last value.